# LaTeX - Lots of sections (with no content) running of the edge of the page?

Tags: latex, tex, text-formatting

I have a LaTeX document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{1}
\section{2}
\section{3}
\section{4}
\section{5}
\section{6}
\section{7}
\section{8}
\section{9}
\section{10}
\section{11}
\section{12}
\section{13}
\section{14}
\section{15}
\section{16}
\section{17}
\section{18}
\section{19}
\section{20}
\section{21}
\section{22}
\section{23}
\section{24}
\section{25}
\section{26}
\section{27}
\section{28}
\section{29}
\section{30}

\end{document}
```

Lots of section headings, but no text in

It produces something like this:
[image]

As you can see it keeps all the section headings on one page, and won't break it into 2 pages. Everything above 26 has disappeared off the end of the page.

Is there anyway to get LaTeX to split these sections across multiple pages? I can't easily change the actual content of body, since it's autogenerated. I can change the preamble though. Is there anyway to do this by changing the preamble?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677426/latex-printing-only-first-two-pages-of-a-document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding \mbox{} after a section heading would allow the page break. You could introduce it globally in the preamble by:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@afterheading{\mbox{}}
\makeatother
```

or

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@afterheading\expandafter{\@afterheading\mbox{}}
\makeatother
```

like in this [expandafter example](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/plaintex/expandafter/).

Answer (score 2):

Stefan's solution didn't work for me, causing problems with the table of contents.

I couldn't work out how to use deinst's answer (sectsty package) either.

What did work for me was this

```tex
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\part}{\mbox{}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\mbox{}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\mbox{}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\mbox{}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\mbox{}}{}{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this with the [sectsty](https://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package